# Why are TCP Packets going from my pc to server owned by EdgeCast Networks, Inc.?

Tags: tcp, packet-analysis

I am seeing a lot of entries like this in my `Netgear DGN 1000` log for the last few weeks:

```
Wed, 2015-11-04 20:36:56 - TCP Packet - Source:192.168.0.2,63272 Destination:68.232.44.114,80 - [BLOCK]
```

From http://www.whois.com/whois/68.232.44.114 I have learned that the server is owned by `EdgeCast Networks, Inc.`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. It is not clear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. Specifically, we can't answer this because we have no idea what devices/applications/services are on your network. I will add that EdgeCast is a CDN, so it is most likely something on one of your devices is requesting something (media, updates, etc).

Comment: How can I trace which program is initiating the packet transfer? Should I use WireShark?

Comment: @YLearn If you want me to run any command and post the output here, you may mention that.

Comment: What is being blocked is an HTTP request, so you should be able to capture that traffic and at least see what is being requested which may or  
may not be able to help. You can also try to tie down which processes are using the ports in the requests with netstat or other tools. However this topic would not generally be on-topic here, especially since your question is off-topic for other reasons (consumer devices, end-user, etc). You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su] where it may fit better.

Comment: @YLearn Can you migrate it to Super User?

Comment: Generally we don't migrate posts unless they already have answers or would be much too difficult to copy/paste into another site. Another bit that might help, but a quick search shows that among EdgeCast customers are Wordpress.com, Tumblr, Twitter and Pinterest (not saying these customers don't use other CDNs as well either). It is also been bought by Verizon, so many of their services likely use it as well.

Comment: @YLearn See here: https://superuser.com/questions/997759/why-are-tcp-packets-going-from-my-pc-to-server-owned-by-edgecast-networks-inc

Comment: @SusanW.Burr I am unsure if you would see this for a blocked connection but netstat -anb will show you the process responsible for a connection that has not yet been closed. Specially the -b flag.